# Can I convert a decimal int to HEX number?

Tags: arduino, hex, decimal

I would like to covert a decimal number (between 0 to  65536) to a hex number. Can I do it in Arduino script? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/) to format a number as hex, e.g. something like

```
//lets be sure our integer is in desired range
myinteger=min(max(myinteger, 0), 65535);

//buffer big enough for 4 hex digits + terminating null
char hexbuffer[5];
sprintf(hexbuffer, "%04x", myinteger);
```

Comment: Thanks! what is a hex buffer?

Comment: and what is the second input mean?

Comment: % introduces a placeholder, 0 means 'zero pad', 4 means '4 digits' and x means 'format as hex'

Comment: hexbuffer is a char* - see doc link for sprintf